# Jackson ObjectMapper - readValue fails when target object has a Map field

Tags: java, android, jackson

I guess this might have been asked earlier, but could not find exactly what I was looking for. So here it goes.

My JSON looks like this -

```
{
    "verticals": [
        {
            "name": "vertical1",
            "icon": "icon1",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "name": "vertical2",
            "icon": "icon2",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "config": {
        "vertical1": [
            {
                "title": "Section1",
                "icon": "icon1",
                "prefs": [
                    {
                        "type": "type1",
                        "opts": [
                            {
                                "name": "pref_store_key",
                                "value": "filter-prefix-food"
                            }
                        ],
                        "icons": [
                            "icon3",
                            "icon4"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "type2",
                        "opts": [
                            {
                                "name": "pref_store_key",
                                "value": "filter-prefix-cue"
                            }
                        ],
                        "icons": [
                            "icon5",
                            "icon6"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "vertical2": [
            {
                "title": "Section1",
                "icon": "icon1",
                "prefs": [
                    {
                        "type": "type1",
                        "opts": [
                            {
                                "name": "pref_store_key",
                                "value": "filter-prefix-food"
                            }
                        ],
                        "icons": [
                            "icon3",
                            "icon4"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "type2",
                        "opts": [
                            {
                                "name": "pref_store_key",
                                "value": "filter-prefix-cue"
                            }
                        ],
                        "icons": [
                            "icon5",
                            "icon6"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My classes are -

```
public class FeatureConfigData {
    private Map<String, List<ItemConfig>> config = null;
    private List<Vertical> verticals = null;

    public List<ItemConfig> getItemConfig(String vertical) {
        if (config == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return config.get(vertical);
        }
    }

    public List<Vertical> getVerticals() {
        return verticals;
    }

    public Map<String, List<ItemConfig>> getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    public void setConfig(Map<String, List<ItemConfig>> config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}

public class ItemConfig {
    private String title = null;
    private String icon = null;
    private List<Pref> prefs = null;

    public static class Pref {
        private String type = null;
        private List<String> icons = null;
        private List<Opt> opts = null;

        public String getType() { return type; }
        public List<String> getIcons() { return icons; }
        public List<Opt> getOpts() { return opts; }
    }

    public static class Opt {
        private String name;
        private String value;

        public String getName() { return name; }
        public String getValue() { return value; }
    }

    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public String getIcon() { return icon; }
    public List<Pref> getPrefs() { return prefs; }
}
```

I am de-serializing the json string with this -

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                    .enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
FeatureConfigData config = objectMapper.readValue(json, FeatureConfigData.class);
```

Why is the config field coming out to be null in my case and not getting populated? Do I need to do something else to ensure that Jackson understands that map keys are "vertical1", "vertical2" etc?

Note, this configuration drives the actual name/number of the verticals. So it's not an option to replace map> with a class with fields vertical1, vertical2 etc.

Comment: I can't reproduce: your code with your JSON causes an exception. If I remove the call to `enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL)`, it works fine.

Comment: By works fine do you mean no crash or the objects being created/populated properly?

Comment: objects being created/populated properly.